# data.table join rolling forward ONCE

Tags: r, data.table

I want to find the next and only the next valid point in one table based on a column in another table

```
library(data.table)
price = data.table(date = as.IDate(c("2000-01-01", "2000-02-01","2000-03-01","2000-04-01")), close = c(101,102,103,104))
meetings = data.table(date = as.IDate(c("2000-01-02", "2000-02-02")), rateDecision=c("rise","keep"))

price
#          date close
# 1: 2000-01-01   101
# 2: 2000-02-01   102
# 3: 2000-03-01   103
# 4: 2000-04-01   104

meetings
#          date rateDecision
# 1: 2000-01-02         rise
# 2: 2000-02-02         keep
```

Desired output is to find the next price after a rate meeting. That is

```
         date rateDecision close 
1: 2000-01-01           NA   101 
2: 2000-02-01         rise   102 
3: 2000-03-01         keep   103 
4: 2000-04-01           NA   104
```

Notice the `NA` in the row 2000-04-01. Rolling join doesn't work. Specifying `roll=30` will work for this case, but not generally when dates are not evenly spaced.

```
meetings[price, on  = "date", roll=TRUE]
#          date rateDecision close
# 1: 2000-01-01           NA   101
# 2: 2000-02-01         rise   102
# 3: 2000-03-01         keep   103
# 4: 2000-04-01         keep   104
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to add an index column:

```
ans = meetings[, I := .I][price, on="date", roll=TRUE]
#          date rateDecision  I close
# 1: 2000-01-01           NA NA   101
# 2: 2000-02-01         rise  1   102
# 3: 2000-03-01         keep  2   103
# 4: 2000-04-01         keep  2   104
```

We can now replace all but first with `NA` for each `I`.

```
ans[ans[, .(idx=.I[-1L]), by=I]$idx, rateDecision := NA][]
```

Comment: Thanks! That also solves my complementary problem of rolling join but excluding matching rows, ie change `.I[-1L]` to `.I[1L]`